# Run NSIS installer from a C++ application with out prompting UAC permission

Tags: c++, nsis

I have C++ application running as service. And I want to start my NSIS installer silently from that service. Is it possible? If yes how can I achieve this?

Comment: Under which account is the service running? Does the installer need to write to any admin-level storage areas? Did you set RequestExecutionLevel in the .nsi?

Comment: The account running is Admin. I have some script that changes registry entries. Yes I tried RequestExecutionLevel in .nsi file but no help.

Comment: Who do you want to run the installer as? The same user as your service (probably SYSTEM) or a normal user account that just happens to be logged in?

Comment: Can I start the installer as the same user as my service (SYSTEM) and skip the UAC prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to start the installer as the same user as your service and this service runs at integrity level high or system then you can just use [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`ShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) to start the installer.

If you want to start the installer as a user that is currently logged in you need to use `CreateProcessAsUser` but things get complicated if you go this route. There might not be any logged in users or there might be more than one. Once you have decided which user you want to start the process as then you can get their token with `WTSQueryUserToken`.